# Are Borel sets preserved by an open continuous map?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Does an open, continuous function defined on a compact metric space to itself send Borel sets to Borel sets?

Comment: Does this question have any motivation and/or you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Well, it is what i need to finish a long problem. It would be nice to know if Im trying to prove something false. Im trying to prove that the class of sets that are sent to borel is a sigma algebra.

Comment: By the way, the function is also surjective

Comment: might be helpful http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm146/fm14631.pdf